# get computer from OU

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have a code to get a list of all the computers within a domain.

Now i need to just get the computers which are within a particular OU and not the rest of the machines.

so here is my code to get all the machines from a domain, this works perfectly fine:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + selectDomain);
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
        mySearcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
        mySearcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;

        foreach (SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
        {
            //"CN=SGSVG007DC"
            string ComputerName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Name;
            if (ComputerName.StartsWith("CN="))
                ComputerName = ComputerName.Remove(0, "CN=".Length);
            compList.Add(ComputerName);
        }

        mySearcher.Dispose();
        entry.Dispose();
```

any suggestions?? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the OU to your directory entry, so instead of taking the root of your domain as being the search path, it takes the domain + OU as being the search path.

See "Enumerating objects in an OU" @ http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx

I see from your commments that you're having issues here, so let's put this simply - note that this code isn't tested, but should clarify...

```
string selectDomain = "CN=myCompany,CN=com";
string selectOU = "OU=LosAngeles,OU=America";
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + selectOU + "," + selectDomain);
```

That essentially gives you the string of "LDAP://OU=LosAngeles,OU=America,CN=MyCompany,CN=com" as the new directory entry. You **must** specify the full LDAP path, not just the OU or the domain.

Comment: i tried this:DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=" + selectedOU); but i get an error : System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.

Comment: so i have my OU= Domain Controller and domain= freeTest.test.com

therefor i have DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + "OU = Domain Controller"+ "," + "CN = freeTest.test, CN = com");

am i doing the right thing?? thanks

Comment: after applying the above i still get error: "System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred."

Comment: "LDAP://OU=Domain Controller,CN=freeTest,CN=Test,CN=com" - think of it as DNS, where periods are seperators.

Comment: Then I'd say you either have something wrong with the LDAP string, in that it's malformed or it's just incorrect, or the account that your application is running as does not have rights to enumerate AD.

Comment: @user175086 `DistinguishedName` is tricky to get right for beginner. First, you shouldn't add any space around `=`. So, don't do `OU = Domain Controller`. Do `OU=Domain Controller`. Second, the last part is usually about domain. If your domain DNS name is like freeTest.test.com, then very likely the corresponding distingished name segment should be like `DC=freeTest,DC=test,DC=com`. So, you can try `LDAP://OU=Domain Controller,DC=freeTest,DC=test,DC=com`. If this still doesn't work, download `ADSI edit` from Microsoft and check the `distingishedName` of your OU using this tool

Comment: in the ldap path, you should ose "OU=tier2OU,OU=tier1OU,DC=company,DC=com" DC instead of CN.

CN = Common Name
OU = Organizational Unit
DC = Domain Component

Answer (score 1):

try to use this Directory entry:

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://OU={0},{1}", ouName, selectDomain));

Comment: i tried this but i get an error : "System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072032): An invalid dn syntax has been specified."

Comment: You're probably not specifying the LDAP string correctly. It must be the fully qualified entry, for example "LDAP://OU=LosAngeles,OU=America,CN=MyCompany,CN=com" - set a breakpoint and check to make sure that the formatted LDAP string is correct.

Answer (score 0):

i tried all the above.. but it did not work... so this is what i tried and it worked.

i understand this is not the best way but its the only way working for me... any suggestion.. thanks

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + selectedDomain);
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=organizationalUnit)");
            mySearcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
            mySearcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;
            foreach (SearchResult temp in mySearcher.FindAll())
            {
                Global.logger.Debug("OU = " + temp.Properties["name"][0].ToString());
                DirectoryEntry ou = temp.GetDirectoryEntry();
                DirectorySearcher mySearcher1 = new DirectorySearcher(ou);
                mySearcher1.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
                mySearcher1.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
                mySearcher1.PageSize = int.MaxValue;

                if (temp.Properties["name"][0].ToString() == selectedOU)
                {
                    foreach (SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher1.FindAll())
                    {
                        //"CN=SGSVG007DC"
                        string ComputerName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Name;
                        Global.logger.Debug("ComputerName = " + resEnt.Properties["name"][0].ToString());
                        if (ComputerName.StartsWith("CN="))
                            ComputerName = ComputerName.Remove(0, "CN=".Length);
                        compList.Add(ComputerName);
                    }
                }

                mySearcher1.Dispose();
                ou.Dispose();
            }

            mySearcher.Dispose();
            entry.Dispose();
```