# Directory Searcher - Searching multiple OU's

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a project where i have to pull some Active Directory information on all our servers.
The thing is i ONLY wan't the servers in AD, and not all the desktop computers.
The servers are located in multiple sub directories, for each location.

I was able to filter on operating system like this, but as some of them are cluster servers AD havn't picked up the OS of the ones hosted on those so I need to create a filter or some logic that only looks in the OU's called Servers.

This is what i currently have:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path);

            // Create a DirectorySearcher object.
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            // Set a filter for users with the name test.
            // Search specific computer replace OperatingSystem=Windows*Server* with anr=<servername>
            mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(OperatingSystem=Windows*Server*))";

            mySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            results = mySearcher.FindAll();
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dnshostname");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Site");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Description");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Location");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingsystem");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingsystemservicepack");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingsystemversion");
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("managedBy");

            con.Open();

            foreach (SearchResult searchResult in results)
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Servername", Convert.ToString(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["cn"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DNSHostname", Convert.ToString(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["dnshostname"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Convert.ToString(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site", Convert.ToString(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["Site"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Convert.ToString(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["Location"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OS", Convert.ToString(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["operatingsystem"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OSServicePack", Convert.ToString(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["operatingsystemservicepack"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OSVersion", Convert.ToString(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["operatingsystemversion"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ManagedBy", Convert.ToString(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["managedBy"].Value));

                if (searchResult.Path.Contains("OU=Test") == true)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsTestServer", 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsTestServer", 0);
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more search today i found the solution here on the website
[get computer from OU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161157/get-computer-from-ou)